# Disabled all input in angular-formly

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I have 2 form and 2 state in angularjs. Form 1 (state 1) contains inputs like: input, select... And form 2 (state 2) is displayed when form1 is submitted. All fields in form2 is the same fields in form 1 but they must to be disabled. I passed all fields from form 1 to form 2 to by using `$stateParams`like that `vm.fields = $stateParams.fieldForm1`; So what can I do to **disable all fields at form 2**

Form 1: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Sxjo.png)

And form 2: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGqML.png)

Comment: you can use `ng-disable="condition"` to disable a input. condition is a boolean or an expression who return a boolean, for example: `form.$valid`

Comment: I deleted my answer because I didn't notice that it was an `angular-formly` related. I'll check my code and see if I did something similar and post it as a new answer. I love formly, but the documentation of this is terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of angular formly there is an option called `formState`which you need to set.

```
<body ng-app="formlyExample" ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
   <div>
      <formly-field options="vm.checkboxField" model="vm.options.formState"></formly-field>
   </div>
</body>
```

In controller level you will have to set formState like this:

```
(function() {
'use strict';
  var app = angular.module('formlyExample', ['formly', 'formlyBootstrap']);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function MainCtrl($scope, formlyVersion) {
  vm.env = {
      angularVersion: angular.version.full,
      formlyVersion: formlyVersion
    };
  var vm = this;

  vm.options = {
      formState: {
        disabled: true
      }
  }

});
})();
```

And to update formState for all fields you can do:

```
angular.forEach(vm.fields, function(field) {
      field.expressionProperties = field.expressionProperties || {};
      field.expressionProperties['templateOptions.disabled'] = 'formState.disabled';
});
```

Comment: Thank you^^. It works with single field. How does it work with fieldGroup? http://angular-formly.com/#/example/integrations/angular-material

Comment: I do it by using for loop with field.fieldGroup array. Thank you so much for helping me

Comment: good to hear that.I suggest you to post your findings as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

True answer when using fieldGroup. In controller:

```
vm.options = {
          formState: {
            disabled: true
          }
        };
 angular.forEach(vm.fields, function(field) {
                if(field.fieldGroup == null) {
                  field.expressionProperties = field.expressionProperties || {};
                  field.expressionProperties['templateOptions.disabled'] = 'formState.disabled';
                }else {
                    var i = 0;
                    for(i=0; i< field.fieldGroup.length; i++){
                        field.fieldGroup[i].expressionProperties = field.fieldGroup[i].expressionProperties || {};
                        field.fieldGroup[i].expressionProperties['templateOptions.disabled'] = 'formState.disabled';

                    }
                }
            });
```